# Insertar barra invertida (/) después de los dos carácteres automaticamente mientras se escribe en un input de un formulario

Tags: javascript

Estoy creando un campo de **fecha de expiración** para los detalles de la tarjeta de crédito como método de pago para una subscripción premium en un formulario HTML.

Me gustaría un código JavaScript que hiciese el trabajo de insertar una barra invertida automáticamente después de los dos carácteres. Y si el usuario ya insertó la barra invertida en el carácter tres (como casos de copiar-pegar), detectar si se insertó o no.

Por ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

(Mientras se escribe) a:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nada más y nada menos que eso, en una pieza de JavaScript.

He probado
**HTTPS : // forum.jquery.com/topic/auto-slash-in-date-field**
Nada funciona.

Gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: Bienvenido Jose Antonio, te sugiero agregues lo que has intentado para que tu pregunta este más completa. Realiza el [tour] y revisa [ask]., saludos.

Comment: @Jorgesys La pregunta es clara, objectiva y concreta, y como último, la pregunta ya está completa y se entiende perfectamente.

Comment: @JoseAntonio la pregunta es clara. Lo que se te pide, es que digas que cosas has probado y buscado y no han funcionado

Comment: Ya añadí un enlace que probe y no funciona

Comment: He probado el script del enlace que has dejado y funciona. Comparte el codigo que estas usando que es el que te da el error para poder analizar en que parte falla.

Comment: Esta comunidad no es lugar para expresiones así.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con este código:

```
$('#').on('change keyup', function(ev){
  var self = $(this);
  var val = self.val();
  if(val.length == 2 && ev.which != 8) self.val(val + '/');
  else if(val.length > 2 && val.charAt(2) != '/') self.val(val.substring(0, 2) + '/' + val.substring(2, 6));
}).attr('maxlength',7);
```

Answer (score 0):

Y si usas esto:

```
<input type="date">
```

De esta manera puedes guardarlo así **08/08/2017** o así **08-08-2017** y luego si lo deseas lo puedes cambiar con un *replace*.